# How to mock object inside using statement, inside static class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

```
public static class ClassA
{
     public static void MethodA()
     {
          using(var classB = new ClassB())
          {
               classB.DoSomething();
          }
     }
}
```

I have been tasked with refactoring some really old unit tests that hit the DB, and really don't need to... Also, I've been asked to avoid touching the tested code if at all possible.  In one of them, I have the above situation...

How can I mock (or replace outright, such as `type.GetField("classB").SetValue` ) either classB or ClassB?

Thank you.

Comment: Without doing some kind of code-weaving using Rosyln or Cecil, I'm not so sure that this is a simple task.

Comment: Typically you'd change it to pass in a Factory to create the `ClassB` for you and mock both the factory and the returned value, but if you cannot change the code then you're pretty much left with not mocking it (which is not necessarily a bad thing depending on what it does) or as Ron mentioned doing some complicated stuff.  And honestly is adding complexity to code just to mock something out for unit tests worth it?  The answer is not always "Yes".

Comment: Thanks, guys.  After some refactoring, and removing the using statement entirely, I was able to get the method to be testable.  :)